# How to calculate to actual calcium content in a pudding mix

Tags: everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry

How can I determine the calcium (Ca2+ ion) content in pudding mix given the amount of milk, number of servings made with one package, the percent of recommended daily dose of calcium per serving, and the recommended daily dose of calcium?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! If you have questions about how to beautify your posts, have a look at the [help]. Do you want to know more about this site, please take the [tour]. I am really not very sure what you are actually asking, and I guess there is some information missing anyway. It also reads like a [homework question](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. You can [edit] your question, to add more information.

Comment: I've changed the title of your question. If you think that it's misleading, please feel free to use the rollback function. According to the [USDA database](http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/181?fg=&manu=&lfacet=&format=&count=&max=35&offset=&sort=&qlookup=01212), dry milk contains about 912 mg calcium in 100 g of the milk powder. I hope that helps for your calculation.